# Meaning and Purpose of JavaScript openCallBack: Function contextMenu

Tags: jquery, callback, contextmenu

I am currently using the this [contextMenu 3Dot Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Material-Design-Context-Menu-jQuery-3Dot-Context-Menu.html) and in html page javascript code it requires the options declaration

```
 var options = {
        openCallBack: function(contextMenu) {
        contextMenu.disableMenuItem("Warning Item");
    }
  };
```

and in the actual plugin code there is a the following code that acts on this declaration

```
    if (options != null && typeof options !== "undefined" )        {
     if (typeof options.openCallBack !== "undefined") {
            options.openCallBack(self);
     }
    }...
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to the purpose or meaning of the `options.openCallBack(self)` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **openCallBack** you could define your function which will dynamically change state of the context menu items or perform any other actions when menu is being opened by click, before it is shown:

```
function ContextMenu(contextContainerID, menuItemClickCallback, options)
{
    // skipped

    this.contextMenuContainer.click(function(e){

        // skipped

        if (options != null && typeof options !== "undefined" )
        {
            if (typeof options.openCallBack !== "undefined")
            {
                options.openCallBack(self);
            }
        }

        // skipped

        contextMenu.show();
        return false;
    });

    // skipped
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  Okay that is very helpful.  The part of the answer that had escaped me is that the operation occurs before the contextMenu is shown.